# Make FileReader read every fourth line with a loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, bufferedreader

**My problems is** that I have to arrange, when searching for a customer, arrange the while loop to only examine every fourth line read.

This is the code I already have on this problem:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customers.txt"));
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    ...
}

br.close();
```

Does anybody know what needs to be at the place of "..."?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call br.readLine() 3 times at the end of the loop, discarding the output:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customers.txt"));
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    ...
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){ br.readLine(); }
}

br.close();
```

Comment: I think your solution is better (i.e. cheaper) than mine which uses counter arithmetic to check for every 4th iteration.

Comment: @J.D. Oke , but can you show me how to get it in my code because I have no clue :p

Comment: So now I can lose the "..." and it will read the fourth line? Do you also know the answer to this question ?[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589977/checking-if-a-customers-name-is-already-in-a-txt-file-with-filereader)

Comment: I think `br.readLine(); br.readLine(); br.readLine();` is more efficient than the loop, but any compiler will unroll it anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of

```
int i = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   i++;
   if (i % 4 == 0)
   {
      // if i is divisible by 4, then
      // your actual code will get executed
      ...
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customers.txt"));
String line;
int count 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (count!=3)
        count++;
    else {
        // Do something?
        count=0;
    }

}

br.close();
```